# Passing a javascript variable to XML body node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I would like to pass the variable that I get from a post request into xml body to make a call to a webservice. How do I pass javascript variables to xml ?

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const sorguNo= req.body.sorguNo;
```

> the variable that I get from post request

```
      const url = 'Url';
       const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
      'soapAction': 'Soap Action'
         };
    const xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
      '<soap:Header>' +
        '<AuthHeader xmlns="http:">' +
          '<userName>username</userName>' +
           '<password>password</password>' +
        '</AuthHeader>' +
      '</soap:Header>' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
        '<xmlns="http:..">' +
          '<sonucNo></sonucNo>' +
```

> here I would like to use the variable in sonucNo field

```
        '</>' +
      '</soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';
```

Comment: Your xlm is just a string. You can use **template strings** to create a multi-line string where you can insert variables.

Comment: As you said using backticks solved the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const sonucNo = "hello";
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope>
    <sonucNo>${sonucNo}</sonucNo>
  </soap:Envelope>`;

console.log(xml);
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to xml injection